# Response.Redirect not redirecting properly

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis

I have this site lets call it **www.mysite.com** I use the sight to show users some images. for example : user will request an image as below(Encrypted of course)
for example mysite.com/download.aspx**id?123123admaodko39032l2k**

mysite.com/content/images/1.jpg **(After Encryption)**

The problem I am having is that once I do a `Response.Redirect("mysite.com/content/images/1.jpg",false)` after unencrypting the url the  url I am directed to is

**mysite.com/mysite.com/content/images/1.jpg** 
notice how mysite.com is repeated twice.

I am not sure if any trick is done from the IIS configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Remove mysite.com from the url.

```
Response.Redirect("content/images/1.jpg",false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that it would solve the issue I am asking why is this behavior. any idea

Comment: Response.redirect assumes you are giving it a relative path unless the url starts with http://

Comment: Better still would probably be to use application rooted URLs (e.g. `~/content/images/1.jpg`) so that the code works consistently however it's hosted and wherever the code is running.